# Find all solutions for $A=1$ where $A=\left(1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\right)\cdot e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

*As all my previous questions, this one is no homework.*

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where
>   $f(x)=\left(1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\right)\cdot e^{-x}$
>
> Also, A = $\left(1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\right)\cdot e^{-x}$
>
> Find all solutions for $A=1$.

$$1=\left(1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{e^{x}}$$

$$e^{x}=\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+x+1$$

$$x=ln \left( \frac{1}{2}x^{2}+x+1 \right)$$

We know that $ln(1) = 0$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+x+1=1$$

$$\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+x=0$$

$$x^{2}+2x=0$$

$$x(x+2)=0$$

$$x=0$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$x=ln \left( \frac{1}{2}x^{2}+x+1 \right)$$

$$0=ln \left( \frac{1}{2}\cdot0+0+1 \right)$$

$$0=ln(1)$$

$$0=0$$

So the only solution would be $x=0$ (Actually, there is also $x=-2$ but you don't get to $ln(1)$ with it so I ignored it.)

I hope everything is alright? Or it's all wrong?

Comment: It may happen that $\ln\left(\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+x+1\right) =x$ without having $x=0$. The only good method I know to answer your problem is studying the function $f$...

Comment: we have $\mathrm{e}^x \approx 1+ x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+.\cdots$ so it looks like you have some careful limits to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derivation is not mathematically rigorous when you suddenly are interested into making the parenthesis equal to 1. Why that ? A priori, there could be solutions with $a=ln(b)$ without $b$ equal to 1.

Instead, if you have a look at the graphics, it gives you the way to follow:

[image]

In fact, this smooth function is strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$ with $f(0)=1$ (you prove it rigorously by showing that its derivative is $< 0$ everywhere on these intervals), thus crosses level $y=1$ once, getting in this way the unique solution $x=0$.

Edit : Polynomial $\left(1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\right)$ is constituted by the first 3 terms of the series expansion of $e^x$. The more terms are taken, the flatter is the resulting graphics around $0$. Here is for example the graphical representation of the function defined by $f(x)=\left(1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{1}{24}x^4\right)e^{-x} $ (roughly speaking, in the vicinity of $x=0$, it is $\approx e^{x}e^{-x}=1$):

[image]

Comment: So my solution is correct but the way I came to that solution is not, right?
It's not easy for me to think "ahh I need to use the monotony! and now I conclude that..." : /

Comment: That's right... And the use of drawings is sometimes crucial to drive our intuition to valid reasoning modes...

Comment: I have added an Edit to my solution.